# inno setup : How to get the tcp connections list in windows?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I tried to create an installer to check the current transmission control protocol connections on **windows64** machine. Is it possible to create?

am going to use command line using extern. if I give ls -lf it will returns all the files which are currently running on

```
[code]
const
GetFileExInfoStandard = $0;

type 
FILETIME = record 
LowDateTime:  DWORD; 
HighDateTime: DWORD; 
end; 
WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA = record 
FileAttributes: DWORD; 
CreationTime:   FILETIME; 
LastAccessTime: FILETIME; 
LastWriteTime:  FILETIME; 
  FileSizeHigh:   DWORD; 
  FileSizeLow:    DWORD; 
end;

SYSTEMTIME = record 
  Year:         WORD; 
  Month:        WORD; 
  DayOfWeek:    WORD; 
  Day:          WORD; 
  Hour:         WORD; 
  Minute:       WORD; 
  Second:       WORD; 
  Milliseconds: WORD; 
end;   

function GetFileAttributesEx ( 
  FileName:             string;
  InfoLevelId:          DWORD;
  var FileInformation:  WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA
  ): Boolean; 
external 'GetFileAttributesExA@kernel32.dll stdcall'; 

function FileTimeToSystemTime(
  FileTime:           FILETIME;
  var SystemTime:     SYSTEMTIME
  ): Boolean; 
external 'FileTimeToSystemTime@kernel32.dll stdcall';
var
TmpfileName: String;
i,j,ResultCode:integer;
ExecStdout,processes:Tarrayofstring;
Page:TInputOptionWizardPage;

procedure initializeWizard;
begin
  TmpFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\processes.txt';
  Exec('cmd.exe','/C netstat > "' + TmpFileName + '"',
  '',SW_HIDE,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
  Page := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome,
  'Current Running processes on your      computer',
  'Displays All Running  processes on this machine, selecte any process
   to terminate','Seleet Any one from the list, Click on next'+#13+
  'Note: Do not select System processes this may cause damage to your machine..'
  ,  True, True); 
  end;

 function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
 begin
 if CurPageID = wpwelcome then
 begin
 if LoadStringsFromFile(TmpFileName, ExecStdout) then
      begin
       for i:=3 to GetArrayLength(ExecStdout)-1 do
        begin
         setarraylength(processes,i-2)
          processes[i-3]:='';
         for j:=1 to length(Execstdout[i]) do
            begin  
             if not ((Execstdout[i][j]=' ') and (Execstdout[i][j+1]=' ')) then
               begin
                processes[i-3]:=processes[i-3]+execstdout[i][j];
               end;
               if ((Execstdout[i][j]=' ') and (Execstdout[i][j+1]=' ')) then
               j:=length(Execstdout[i]);

            end;
            page.add(processes[i-3]);
         end;
      end;

 Result:=true;
 end;
 if CurPageID = page.id then
 begin
 result:=true;
 end;
  if CurPageID = wpReady then
 Result:=true;
```

end;

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: can you please tell me what are the functions i need to use to get this

Comment: I would use the [`GetTcpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366026(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: No. I don't have such code. I don't even know if it's possible to use that function from Inno Setup Pascal Script. Better would be to wrap it into an external DLL.

Comment: @TLama okay i will try to do that

Comment: @Tlama the following code was i tried but using netstat nothing happens but ls -of it is working

Comment: [code]procedure initializeWizard;
begin
TmpFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\processes.txt';
Exec('cmd.exe','/C netstat > "' + TmpFileName + '"', '', SW_HIDE,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
Page := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome,'Current Running processes on your computer', 'Displays All Running processes on this machine,selecte any process to terminate','Seleet Any one from the list, Click on next'+#13+'Note: Do not select System processes this may cause damage to your machine..' ,  True, True); 
end;

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're asking. You just made from this question a moving target... Could you edit your post into some final question, please ? P.S. code in comments is really unreadable...

Comment: @TLama yes i did the changes and i have given code also have a look please

Comment: @TLama take a look at ""procedure initializeWizard; "" where we have one line to use command line "<cmd.exe> /c netstat' " its compiling successfully but no result.. but if i give " <cmd.exe> /c ls -of " i got all the list.. but i want only TCP connection list. To check the TCP connections we generally use "netstat" command so that am using that one. If you have any idea regarding this please share with me.. till you did not get my point am ready to explain again :)

Comment: @TLama hi, i made a code to show TCP connections are present in our machine  .  Thanks for your help. I cant post my code here because i dont have that many reputation am a new user

Comment: I didn't help you. I've suggested the use of Windows API. The rest about netstat I didn't get. And, you can post and accept your own answer. That's allowed even with low reputation, isn't it ?

Comment: @TLama i have posted my code below here once have a look please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is perfectly working but it may take half minute to show the result.

```
[Code]

function NextButtonClick(CurPage: Integer): Boolean;
var
    TmpFileName, ExecStdout: string;
    ResultCode: integer;
begin
   if CurPage = wpWelcome then begin
   TmpFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\ipconfig_results.txt';
   Exec('cmd.exe', '/C netstat > "' + TmpFileName + '"', '', SW_HIDE,
          ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
if LoadStringFromFile(TmpFileName, ExecStdout) then begin

       MsgBox(ExecStdout, mbInformation, MB_OK);
      // do something with contents of file...
     end;
   DeleteFile(TmpFileName);
   end;
   Result := True;
 end;
```